# Confused about terminology for the center of power series; what does "centered at $x=1$" mean?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, definition

I have just learned about power series and have mostly seen the center referred to as the $a$ value in the series of the form $\sum _{n=0}^\infty (x-a)^n$. However, I have also seen the $x$-value referred to as the center, e.g. in "compute the Taylor series of the function around $x = 1$". Does this last statement mean that the $a$ value in the Taylor series will be $1$? I am unsure because they are talking about $x$, not $a$; but $x$ seems to be referred to as the center but I have been taught $a$ is the center when we have a power series of this form.

Comment: In general, the series $\sum a_n(x-a)^n$ represents a function around the point $x=a$, so as they want it represented around $x=1$, you will use $a=1$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop by "in general", do you mean that every power series representing a function represents it around the point $x=a$, or only most of the time this is the case?

Comment: Most of the time. You can choose $a_n$ such that the sum does not converge anywhere except at $x=a$ (where it is obviously equal to $a_0$ as all the other terms vanish), but this is a somewhat pathological case. In all _useful_ cases there will be the disc of convergence centered in $a$ in which it will converge: its "[radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence)" can be calculated as $r=\frac{1}{\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$ (can be infinite if the denominator is zero) and so the series absolutely converges for $|x-a|<r$ and diverges for $|x-a|>r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center is where the point where you evaluate your function is "near". Developping an analytic function near $x = 1$ means that you write it as,
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \alpha_n(x - 1)^n,
$$
where $x$ is close to $1$ or equivalently,
$$
f(1 + x) = \sum_{n \geqslant 0} \alpha_nx^n,
$$
where $x$ is close to $0$ this time. Same thing with Taylor series development where you replace the infinite sum by a finite sum plus a little/great O. Therefore, with your notations, the center indeed refers to the $a$ but $x$ must be close enough to $a$ for the series to converge (at least when the radius of convegrence is finite).